# Passing over errors in loop for my web-scraper

Tags: python, selenium

I currently have a loop running for my web-scraper. If it encounters an error (i.e can't load the page) I have it set to ignore it and continue with the loop.

```
for i in links:
try:
    driver.get(i);
    d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class = "list-details__item__date"]')
    s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class = "list-details__item__score"]')
    m = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="list-breadcrumb__item__in"]')
    o = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@data-bid]');
    l = len(o)
    lm= len(m)
    for i in range(l):
        a = o[i].text
        for i in range(lm):
            b = m[i].text
            c = s[i].text
            e = d[i].text
            odds.append((a,b,c,e))
except:
    pass
```

However, I now wish for there to be a note of some kind when an error was encountered so that I can see which pages didn't load. Even if they are just left blank in the output table, that would be fine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your indentation seems a little off. I'm not sure this will run as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a catch for the exception and then do something with that catch. This should be suitable for your script.

```
import ... (This is where your initial imports are)
import io
import trackback 

for i in links:
    try:
        driver.get(i);
        d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class = "list-details__item__date"]')
        s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class = "list-details__item__score"]')
        m = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="list-breadcrumb__item__in"]')
        o = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@data-bid]');
        l = len(o)
        lm= len(m)
        for i in range(l):
            a = o[i].text
            for i in range(lm):
                b = m[i].text
                c = s[i].text
                e = d[i].text
               odds.append((a,b,c,e))
    except Exception as error_script:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        odds.append('Error count not add')
```

Essentially what happens is that you catch the exception using the `exception Exception as error_script: line. Afterwards , you can print the actual error message to the console using the`traceback.format_exc()`command.

But most importantly you can append a string to the list by passing the append statement in the exception catch and use pass at the end of the exception. `pass` will run the code int he catch and then go to the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I was fixing the indentation before you finished yours.